# ¿Cómo puedo remover la selección del checkbox cuando hago click en la celda de un DataGridView? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Saludos a la comunidad.

Tengo un problema en VB.NET, pasa que en un `DataGridView` que tengo, al hacer click en la celda (no en el checkbox como tal) de un `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` termina seleccionando el checkbox. Se entiende mejor viendo el siguiente gif:

[image]

Repito, el gif de arriba es el que NO DEBERÍA DE SUCEDER, lo que yo busco es bloquear la celda o bloquear el click específicamente en esa columna (aunque podría ser para todo el `DataGridView`, no habría problema). Lo que busco se entiende con el siguiente gif:

[image]

> - Ya me han comentado de que el funcionamiento NORMAL debería ser como el 2do gif, o sea que sin tocar nada de código el 2do gif debe funcionar por default, sin embargo no es mi caso y tampoco he tocado nada a nivel de código como para alterar el funcionamiento del `DataGridView`.
> - Uso Visual Basic y .Net Framework 3.5 en VS2015.

Colocaría todo lo que he intentado, pero realmente he seguido todos los tutoriales que he encontrado y leído la documentación oficial, nada me ha servido. Agradezco cualquier aporte o respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

han pasado 9 meses desde tu publicacion pero me gustaria poner el codigo que yo hice, la diferencia es q yo le doy doble clic a cualquier parte de la fila y con esto marca o desmarca el checkbox, yo encontre esta funcion en alguno de los portales de ayuda pero la adecue a mis necesidades, espero te sirva:

```
 Private Sub DGV_REPORTE_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DGV_REPORTE.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If DGV_REPORTE.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        DGV_REPORTE.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub
Private Function EstadoCheck(ByVal filaposicion As Integer) As Boolean
    Return Me.DGV_REPORTE.Rows(filaposicion).Cells("CANCELAR").Value
End Function
Private Sub DGV_REPORTE_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGV_REPORTE.CellDoubleClick
    If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
        Return
    End If
    If EstadoCheck(e.RowIndex) = True Then
        DGV_REPORTE.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CANCELAR").Value = False
    ElseIf EstadoCheck(e.RowIndex) = False Then
        DGV_REPORTE.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("CANCELAR").Value = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Son 3 sub, el q indica el cambio de la fila, el que valida el check y el doble clic a la fila